# Assigning Vue JS 2 static props in a component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm a little confused with passing static props to a component in the VUEJS 2 documentation.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Passing-a-Number

```
<!-- Even though `42` is static, we need v-bind to tell Vue that -->
<blog-post v-bind:likes="42"></blog-post>
<!-- this is a JavaScript expression rather than a string.       -->
```

`<translation :phrase="language.exit" type="body" lines="3"></translation>`

If I don't bind the prop, I can't see it in the component template.

`<translation :phrase="language.exit" :type="body" :lines="3"></translation>`

If I bind it but there is no data in the app, I get an error. They should be static data assigned in the translation component.

`<translation :phrase="language.exit" :type="'body'" :lines="'3'"></translation>`

Adding single quotes works but it doesn't show this in the documentation.

Am I missing something somewhere?

Edit: Adding the globally registered component

```
Vue.component('translation', {
  props: ['phrase', 'type', 'lines'],
  template: '<span>{{ phrase }} - {{ type}} - {{ lines }}</span>'
});
```

Comment: "If I don't bind the prop, I can't see it in the component template."  Did you define the prop in the child component?  If all you want to do is pass down a static string, your first example will work as long as `type` is still defined _as a prop_ on the child component.  [This example app](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-stonebraker-56v829?file=/src/App.vue) where App.vue passes a static string to HelloWorld.vue shows this.

Comment: Weird, it is working according to the docs now (without binding the data)

Answer (score 1):

In fact, when you write code like this

```
<translation :phrase="language.exit" type="body" lines="3"></translation>
```

It means that you bind type with string `body` and bind lines with string `3`, you should be able to get them through props in component `translation`.

But if you write like this

```
<translation :phrase="language.exit" :type="body" :lines="3"></translation>
```

the attribute type is invalid because `body` is not a variable or anything else.

When you write like this

```
<translation :phrase="language.exit" :type="'body'" :lines="'3'"></translation>
```

It is just the same as the first example, you bind type with string `body`, bind lines with string `3`, if you want to bing type with string and lines with number, you can try this:

```
<translation :phrase="language.exit" type="body" :lines="3"></translation>
```

I hope it will be helpful to you.